# Created an ec-2 launch wordpress instance without key pair

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami, key-pair

I'm pretty new to using amazon web services. I created a new launch instance using WordPress powered by Bitnami and made sure to create a key pair. The key pair I made shows up under the "Key Pair" category however it is not linked to my launch instance. How do I fix this without losing any of the content that's on my current Wordpress site? I want to access the instance through my terminal, however I need the key pair for authentication. Thank you!

Comment: Are not able to use that key pair to ssh to the EC2 instance? What error is it giving you.

Comment: It just says no key pair attached :(

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your situation is:

- Your EC2 instance with WordPress is operating fine
- You did not associate a Keypair with the instance when it was first launched
- Therefore you cannot login to the instance

To fix this, you will need to **copy a keypair onto the boot volume**. This can be done by **accessing it via another computer** (where you *can* login).

The basic steps are:

- Launch another EC2 instance ("**Debug instance**")
- Stop your WordPress instance
- Detach the boot volume of the WordPress instance ("**WordPress volume**")
- Attach the WordPress volume to the Debug instance
- Login to the Debug instance, access the WordPress volume and copy a new keypair to `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` (If you're not sure what to copy, copy the file from the same location in the Debug instance.)
- Unmount and detach the WordPress volume from the Debug instance
- Attach the WordPress volume to the WordPress Instance (as `/dev/xvda`)
- Boot the WordPress volume and try to login
- Terminate the Debug instance

A similar concept is documented here:

- [How to Recover an Unreachable Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598)
- [Lost my key with linux authorized_Keys. Now unable to login into the linux](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=217208)

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough response! Why can't I use the same computer as before? After going through this process, can I use my original computer to ssh into that same instance? Or do I have to use the new computer?

Comment: Your problem is that the Wordpress boot volume does not contain a keypair, therefore it will not let you login. The above process will let you put a keypair on that volume. You will then be able to boot it AND login to it. You need to use the 'Debug Instance' because you need to access the Wordpress disk volume from a machine that lets you login.